# Unbounded knapsack problem with extra reward for certain combinations

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am thinking about a variant of the unbounded knapsack problem, where extra value is added for certain combination of items.

Suppose we have `N` items and the `i`-th item has value `v_i` and weight `w_i`. Suppose we are given a weight limit `W`. For the regular unbounded knapsack problem, each item is allowed to be repeated any number of times and we maximize the total value under the constraint that the total weight does not exceed `W`.

Now let us add a twist. Suppose we are given a list `S_1, S_2, ... , S_K` of subsets of `{1, 2, ..., N}` and positive numbers `a1, a2, ... a_K`. If all the items in `S_j` are present in the items we packed into the knapsack, an extra `a_j` is added to the total value. How do we maximize the total value?

Does this variant problem have a name?

Here is my impractical solution. Suppose we just focus on the subset `{2, 4, 5}` of `{1, 2, ..., N}` . We require that (repetitions of) items 2, 4, 5 must be and only they can be packed into the knapsack, then we know which extra values are added, and it reduces to a normal unbounded knapsack problem on the set `{2, 4, 5}`. Now do this for all subsets of `{1, 2, ..., N}`. Now we have `2^N` problems to solve, which is not practical.